# How do I reverse proxy a URL path?

Tags: nginx, owncloud, bitnami

I have a owncloud server running at owncloud.example.com/owncloud
Its a bitnami install and requires me to access it via the /owncloud path. I have the thing reverse proxied through nginx but it takes me to the bitnami page first from which I have to take a link to the actual path. Or I have to access the url via the complete path. How do I setup my reverse proxy to avoid this. This is my rudimentary setup to just play around with.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name owncloud.example.com;


    location / {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.139:83/;

 }
```

}

Right now the reverse proxy will take me to owncloud.example.com. I need it to take me to owncloud.example without hitting a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you proxy_pass to following:

```
proxy_pass http://192.168.1.139:83/owncloud;
```

It should do the trick. If that's not what you want please describe more carefully.

Comment: That did work but with one caveat. When the redirect happens I get a url like: http://owncloud.example.com:83/owncloud. Any way to remove the port? I tried a proxy_redirect but leads to a too many redirects error.

Comment: It's strange that port is changed. It shouldn't be that way:) 


Could you please provide curl -L -I info?